# DataFrame in list boolean?

Tags: python, pandas

I can select a subset using Boolean indexing as such:

```
df.loc[df['my column'] == 1]
```

What I'd like to do is replace the `== 1` with a list, `[1, 2]`.

Something like:

```
df.loc[df['my column'] in [1,2]]
```

This is the equivalent of a long or statement.

How do I do it nicely with pandas?

(alternative, non-Boolean answers are good too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to test membership in a list of values:

```
df.loc[df['my column'].isin([1,2])]
```

Example:

```
In [18]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':np.arange(5)})
df

Out[18]:
          a  b
0 -0.118930  0
1 -0.129362  1
2  0.822227  2
3  1.781672  3
4 -0.127322  4

In [19]:
df.loc[df['b'].isin([2,4])]

Out[19]:
          a  b
2  0.822227  2
4 -0.127322  4
```